# XSLT: How do I select nodes from a document fragment and/or apply recursion to select nodes when other variables are required?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to apply an algorithm in XSLT that selects a specific hire date provided from a source that has a list of hire and term dates. I need to keep two lists of document fragments, which may or may not have the same number of nodes, in sync as best as possible (this may not be the best approach.) I only want one date to return, and that date needs to be the most recent hire date that is also 91 days after the corresponding termination date. If no dates are found, return the original hire date.

Reading from other posts, I understand that XSLT does not have a "break" statement for for-each, and that recursion is usually the better choice. But I'm having a hard time thinking of how to use recursion, or a template, or even how to succinctly select only the single node that I want out of this list.

Here is a sample source document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
        <name>Kenneth</name>
        <RecentHireDate>2014-12-01-07:00</RecentHireDate>
        <OriginalHireDate>2000-01-01-07:00</OriginalHireDate>
        <TermDate>2014-10-30-07:00</TermDate>
        <Event_History>
            <Effective_Date>2000-01-01-07:00</Effective_Date>
            <Transaction_Types Descriptor="Hire - Hire Employee Event">
                <ID type="Business_Process_Type">Hire Employee</ID>
            </Transaction_Types>
        </Event_History>
        <Event_History>
            <Effective_Date>2014-01-15-08:00</Effective_Date>
            <Transaction_Types Descriptor="Termination - Terminate Employee Event">
                <ID type="Business_Process_Type">Terminate Employee</ID>
            </Transaction_Types>
        </Event_History>
        <Event_History>
            <Effective_Date>2014-02-01-07:00</Effective_Date>
            <Transaction_Types Descriptor="Hire - Hire Employee Event">
                <ID type="Business_Process_Type">Hire Employee</ID>
            </Transaction_Types>
        </Event_History>
        <Event_History>
            <Effective_Date>2014-03-01-07:00</Effective_Date>
            <Transaction_Types Descriptor="Termination - Terminate Employee Event">
                <ID type="Business_Process_Type">Terminate Employee</ID>
            </Transaction_Types>
        </Event_History>
        <Event_History>
            <Effective_Date>2014-09-30-07:00</Effective_Date>
            <Transaction_Types Descriptor="Hire - Hire Employee Event">
                <ID type="Business_Process_Type">Hire Employee</ID>
            </Transaction_Types>
        </Event_History>
        <Event_History>
            <Effective_Date>2014-10-30-07:00</Effective_Date>
            <Transaction_Types Descriptor="Termination - Terminate Employee Event">
                <ID type="Business_Process_Type">Terminate Employee</ID>
            </Transaction_Types>
        </Event_History>
        <Event_History>
            <Effective_Date>2014-12-01-07:00</Effective_Date>
            <Transaction_Types Descriptor="Hire - Hire Employee Event">
                <ID type="Business_Process_Type">Hire Employee</ID>
            </Transaction_Types>
        </Event_History>
    </Report_Entry>
 </Report_Data>
```

And here is a condensed version of the XSLT, that doesn't work right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:foo="Foo"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs foo"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
        <xsl:for-each select="Report_Entry">

            <!-- Gather up all the hire events, sort them descending -->
            <xsl:variable name="hireDates">
                <xsl:for-each select="Event_History[contains(Transaction_Types, 'Hire')]/Effective_Date">
                    <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>

            <!-- Gather up all the term events, sort them descending -->
            <xsl:variable name="termDates">
                <xsl:for-each select="Event_History[contains(Transaction_Types, 'Term')]/Effective_Date">
                    <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>

            <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
            <statusDate>
                <!-- pass in the two document fragment variables, and the previous/original hire date. -->
                <xsl:call-template name="foo:getStatusDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="hireDates" select="$hireDates"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="termDates" select="$termDates"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="originalHire" select="OriginalHireDate"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </statusDate>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="foo:getStatusDate">
        <xsl:param name="hireDates"/>
        <xsl:param name="termDates"/>
        <xsl:param name="originalHire" />

        <xsl:variable name="originalHireDate" select="xs:date($originalHire)"/>

        <!-- Loop over hireDate document fragment to get all the effective dates -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$hireDates/Effective_Date">
            <!-- Save a reference to the current record as an actual date. This is so 
                 I can do a "date diff" of sorts later. -->
            <xsl:variable name="hireDate" select="." as="xs:date"/>
            <xsl:variable name="hirePos">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$termDates/Effective_Date/last() >= position()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$termDates/Effective_Date/last()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

            <!-- Grab the term date that is in the same position as the hire date. 
                 This is what I'm trying to use to keep them in sync (and failing) -->
            <xsl:variable name="termDate" select="$termDates/Effective_Date[$hirePos]" as="xs:date"/>

            <!-- Diff the two dates, which will return an integer for the number of days between. -->
            <xsl:variable name="dayDiffTermRehire" select="days-from-duration($hireDate - $termDate)" as="xs:integer"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$dayDiffTermRehire >= xs:integer(91)">
                    <xsl:sequence select="$hireDate"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:sequence select="$originalHireDate"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried using a function at first, now I'm trying a `call-template`, but the results are basically the same, which is an error in the `dayDiffTermRehire` variable due to, I presume, an incorrect method of selecting appropriate term date and the unequal number of term dates compared to hire dates.

EDIT: For this particular input, the correct hire date would be the `2014-09-30-07:00` because, comparing it to the corresponding termination date, `2014-03-01-07:00`, would be the first date to be greater than 91 days.

More clarity:
Effectively, I need to compare the dates like so. For each row only. Once it gets to the last term date, just return the original hire date.

```
| Hire Dates:      | Term Dates:      |
| 2000-01-01-07:00 |                  |
| 2014-02-01-07:00 | 2014-01-15-08:00 |
| 2014-09-30-07:00 | 2014-03-01-07:00 |
| 2014-12-01-07:00 | 2014-10-30-07:00 |
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. If you have some items in the input document and want a sequence containing them in reversed order then you can do e.g.  `<xsl:variable name="hireDates" select="reverse(Event_History[contains(Transaction_Types, 'Hire')]/Effective_Date)"/>`.

Comment: Which is the result you want? Is a list `<statusDate>2000-01-01-07:00 2014-09-30-07:00 2000-01-01-07:00 2000-01-01-07:00</statusDate>` the correct result for your sample?

Comment: For this particular input, the correct date to return should be the 2014-09-30 date. The corresponding term date would be the 2014-09-30 date. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt to express your description as XSLT/XPath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
        <xsl:for-each select="Report_Entry">

            <!-- Gather up all the hire events, sort them descending -->
            <xsl:variable name="hireDates" select="reverse(Event_History[contains(Transaction_Types, 'Hire')]/Effective_Date/xs:date(.))"/>


            <!-- Gather up all the term events, sort them descending -->
            <xsl:variable name="termDates" select="reverse(Event_History[contains(Transaction_Types, 'Term')]/Effective_Date/xs:date(.))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="count-of-term-dates" select="count($termDates)"/>

            <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
            <statusDate>
                <xsl:variable name="selectedDates" select="$hireDates[let $pos := index-of($hireDates, .) return (days-from-duration(. - $termDates[if ($pos gt $count-of-term-dates) then $count-of-term-dates else $pos]) >= 91)]"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="if (exists($selectedDates[1])) then $selectedDates[1] else xs:date(OriginalHireDate)"/>

            </statusDate>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result for your sample is

```
<name>Kenneth</name>
<statusDate>2014-09-30-07:00</statusDate>
```

Drawback: It is XSLT 3.0 as it uses `let` in XPath, so it will only run with XSLT 3.0 processors like Saxon 9.7 or Exselt or the commercial versions of Saxon 9.6 as available in oXygen.

If you need to do it with XSLT 2.0 then rewrite the variable expression used to

```
            <xsl:variable name="selectedDates" select="for $date in $hireDates, $pos in index-of($hireDates, $date) return $date[days-from-duration(. - $termDates[if ($pos gt $count-of-term-dates) then $count-of-term-dates else $pos]) >= 91]"/>
```

Comment: Interesting...Thanks. I'll have to see if v3 is available.

Comment: @jktravis, I have edited the answer to show how to rewrite that line as an XSLT/XPath 2.0 expression.

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't know how it could get much better than that!

Comment: Does oXygen let you step through XPath expressions? I kind of get how it's working, but I'd like to see it more closing in a debugger. It usually helps me understand better.